# How to update the node tracker programatically in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to update a node in drupal 7 programatically. The node is updating without any issues but the node's tracker does not get updated simultaneoulsy. How do I update the tracker programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a field `changed` in `{node}` table. You have to update this value to current time.